# How can I make Jackson deserialize a JSON into an object wrapped in a generic wrapper that uses factory instantiation?

Tags: java, json

Consider this JSON

```
{
"data": 
    {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Sergey"
    }
}
```

Suppose, I want it to be deserialized into

```java
Data<Person> person;
```

Suppose, `Person` is a simple class with a canonical constructor

```java
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Suppose, `Data` is a bit trickier: it is generic and its instantiation relies on a static factory method. Its no-args constructor is `private` and is not supposed to be used anywhere else

```java
public final class Data<T> {

    private final T data;

    private Data(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static <T> Data<T> build(T data) {
        return new Data<>(data);
    }
}
```

**How do I make Jackson perform that deserialization in the most concise and efficient way possible?** Does [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) provide an exemplary solution to this problem? I heard it now occasionally uses AI-generated text so I want to make sure I can't achieve it in a way that is shorter and clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1.** Annotate your all-args and factory method as `@JsonCreator`

```java
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public final class Data<T> {

    private final T data;

    private Data(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    @JsonCreator
    public static <T> Data<T> build(T data) {
        return new Data<>(data);
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Register the `ParameterNamesModule`. This will help Jackson map constructor/ factory method parameters to their eponymous fields automatically

```java
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
```

**Step 3.** Make sure to create and pass a `TypeReference` object

```java
        TypeReference<Data<Person>> typeReference =
                new TypeReference<>() {};
        Data<Person> deserializedPersonJson =
                objectMapper.readValue(personJson, typeReference);
```